# java.lang.StackOverflowError при использовании рекурсии

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Не работает следующий код (работал при меньшем значении s1):

```
public class Class1 {
    static String[] s = { "", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
   "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
   "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", 
   "W", "X", "Y", "Z" }; //Тут хранятся символы

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long s1 = 37090594994L; //Данное число
        for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++) { //Здесь подбирается последняя буква
            che(s1 - i, s[i], 0); //Для предпоследней буквы
        }
    }

    private static void che(long l, String str, int mult) {
        mult++; // Степень, в которую возводится 24
        for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++) { //подбираем следующую букву
            long tmp = i * mult(mult); //следующий член многочлена

            if (l - tmp == 0) //если больше не найти букв
                System.out.println(s[i] + str); //выводим
            else if (l - tmp > 1) //а если можно найти ещё одну букву
                che(l - tmp, s[i] + str, mult); //то ищем её
        }
    }

    private static long mult(int mult) { //возведение в степень
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= mult; i++)
            result *= 24;
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Компилятор выводит следующее:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2691)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
    at Class1.che(Class1.java:23)
    at Class1.che(Class1.java:23)
    at Class1.che(Class1.java:23)
    at Class1.che(Class1.java:23) и так далее сотню раз...
```

---

Суть задания такова:

> Закодированный пароль s представляет собой число, являющееся
>   значением полинома X(s)= s[1]*24^(n-1) + s[2]*24^(n-2) + … + s[n-1]*24 +
>   s[n], где s[i] - код буквы пароля s, стоящей на i-ом месте. Буквы
>   кодируются подряд по своему расположению в английском алфавите,
>   причем буква A кодируется единицей, B – двойкой и т. д. Помогите
>   подобрать пароль, если записано заданное число 37090594994.

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: s1 у вас больше 2^32-1, что часто является максимальным возможным значением для целого типа. Так что смотрите что там в жабе есть с бОльшим диапазоном, чем 0-2^32

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести простой пример входных и выходных параметров? А то не совсем ясно, что и как.

Comment: При вводе 28850 результат BBBB
AZBB
BAZB
AYZB
BBAZ
AZAZ
BAYZ
AYYZ

Comment: Какой у вас n-ый член полинома?

Comment: StackOverflow - это не только название сайта, но и ошибка переполнения стека в Вашем случае. А чем в java заполняется стек? Может слишком глубокая рекурсия в `che` и стек переполнен параметрами? Попробуйте найти не рекурсивный алгоритм.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас в формулировке задачи ошибка. А точнее, в полиноме. Так же прокомментируйте ваш код. Что делают методы? Что означают параметры? Очевидно только одно, что ошибка возникает из-за бесконечного рекурсивного вызова метода `che`.

Comment: Типа, есть уравнение `s[n] + s[n-1]*24+s[n-2]*576+... = 37090594994`, `1<= s[i] <= 26`, надо подобрать `s[i]`, `s[i]` могут повторяться? Рекурсия не нужна же вроде.

Comment: Добавил немного комментариев и вернул степени в многочлен. Рекурсия нужна, вроде, так как количество подходящих комбинаций символов может быть разное. Но сама задача не важна: код работает при меньшем аргументе s1. Нужно только добиться работы с большими числами.

Comment: Можете вести счётчик вызовов cte и сравнить таким не хитрым способом глубину рекурсии для малого и большого значения s1. Если рекурсия имеет какие-то обозримые пределы (с учётом оперативки), то можно увеличивать размер стека, Ищите в руководствах по JVM как настроить память. Не знаю верно ли это для общего случая, но часто рекурсию можно заменить "нерекурсией".

Comment: ладно, почему оно уходит в SO я понял, 24^8 несколько больше `int result`, в который вы складываете результат в `mult`. Только я пока результата вычисления дождаться не могу. Но вот сейчас придет кто-нибудь математически подкованный, и скажет, что тут надо просто решить уравнение 8ой степени и это легко на бумажке делается :)

Comment: У вас какой-то очень странный полином. Что в первом члене делает n? Что это вообще такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Крч, ответ на вопрос, почему оно так глубоко уходит - метод вычисления степени:

```
private static long mult(int mult) { //возведение в степень
    int result = 1; // int - мало! 24^7 = 4_586_471_424L
    for (int i = 1; i <= mult; i++)
        result *= 24;
    return result;
}
```

Java не контролирует переполнение, поэтому метод выдает неверный результат, разность не равна нулю, рекурсия не прекращается, кончается стек.

Я бы написал так:

```
static long pows[] = new long[8];
static {
    pows[0] = 1;
    for ( int i = 1; i < pows.length; i++ ) {
        pows[i] = pows[i-1]*24;
    }
}
```

Больше 7ой степени вам для вашей задачи не нужно, `24^8 = 110_075_314_176` что больше, чем `37_090_594_994`

Comment: Поставил ограничитель и вставил эти строки, но всё равно не хочет(( Вот как это выглядит: http://itmages.ru/image/view/3278677/1607646d
(Скриншот)

Comment: ссылка не открывается

Comment: Извиняюсь http://itmages.ru/image/view/3278677/1607646d

Comment: Серьезно?.. Окей, прямо по скриншоту смотрим: у вас `mult` = 7, это меньше 8, вы входите на следующий уровень рекурсии. В первой строке метода увеличиваете `mult` на 1, он равен 8, элемента с таким индексом в массиве нет.

Comment: Я бы тебя расцеловал, если бы встретил. А пока вот тебе плюсик))